# Creation of Community Wiki Answer page on banking and related topics

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

It is not a surprise to the regulars here that many of the questions we get on this site are related to money creation, the Federal Reserve, and banking. They usually entail some sort of confusion about common misconceptions about how monetary policy works and/or how banking isn't just some unsustainable Ponzi schemes. We've got so many of questions in this lieu that it may help be helpful to make a wiki page that addresses the major/most common questions related to this area.

This is not saying we rehash an introductory textbook on how monetary policy works necessarily. I'm aware that there are plenty of other resources out there for people to come and understand this material, but one problem is that there are arguably even more materials that obfuscate or mislead an average person about these topics. So this question is posted to ask: **who would be interested in creating a thorough wiki page that we can redirect banking/monetary questions to and is it even necessary to do so in the first place?**

Keep in mind also that I am not the first person to [ask about creating a Wiki related to this](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/nominate-for-community-wiki).

Comment: Interesting idea. However, what's wrong with simply flagging them as duplicate questions (and thereby  providing a link to answer)?

Comment: A lot of times we just don't mark some questions as duplicates. I'm not exactly sure why. It's possible that each new question has a different enough bent that other people will make time to answer them, or that there are just too many of these questions floating around to find the exact question being duplicated. Hence, a catch-all post could be useful.

Comment: Also, what happens to the question once you refer the person to the wiki page? Does the question get closed? If so, it should be just as easy to mark them as a duplicate. My opinion is that we should use the site's standard mechanism for dealing with this issue---mark them as duplicates if they're really the same questions or keep them open if they raise a sufficiently novel line of questioning.

Comment: Fair enough. You can make that an answer if you want, but otherwise I think your reasoning is fine.